# Inline Formset is misbehaving

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have a view for updating a classroom. It does this....

```
@login_required
def classroom_update(request, pk):
    classroom = get_object_or_404(Classroom, pk=pk)

    StudentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Classroom, Student, form=StudentForm, can_delete=False, extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        classroom_form = ClassroomForm(request.POST, instance=classroom)
        student_formset = StudentFormSet(request.POST, instance=classroom)

        if classroom_form.is_valid():
            if student_formset.is_valid():
```

.... And then it breaks right there. I get:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /classroom_update/1
"u'student_set-0-id'"
```

Any ideas why it would be misbehaving?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do formset CRUD in a template with single view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845575/how-to-do-formset-crud-in-a-template-with-single-view)

Comment: I realized the issue was not with CRUD. It won't validate even if I don't change anything on the page. :/